# proof by resolution?

Tags: logic

Consider the following sentence:
$$[(F \implies P)\vee(D \implies P)] \implies [(F \wedge D) \implies P]$$

I am not too familiar with how to prove by resolution, from what I found online, I need to negate the conclusion and convert it to **CNF**, and I came up with the following:
$$(\neg F \vee \neg D \vee P) \wedge (F \wedge D \wedge \neg P) $$
above is what I obtained after applying negation to the whole sentence, and I am assuming it would yield a empty set since one of them has to be *false*, but this is the right way of doing it?

Comment: oops sorry, I fixed the error.

Comment: Exactly; after having applied the "transformation", if you reach teh empty set (or empty clause) this means that the formula is *unsatisfiable*. But, being it the negation of the original formula, this means that the original formula is a *tautology* (because $\varphi$ is *taut* **iff** $\lnot \varphi$ is *unsat*).

Answer (score 1):

This is right. You can further transform the second formula to a set of clauses:

$$\{ \{\neg F, \neg D, P \}, \{ F\}, \{ D\}, \{ \neg P\}  \}.$$

Theses clauses can be used for resoultion (two at a time):

$$\{\underline{\neg F}, \neg D, P \}\quad\{ F\}$$
$$\{\underline{\neg D}, P \}\quad\{ D\}$$
$$\{\underline{P}\}\quad\{ \neg P\}$$
$$\square$$

Since you can derive the empty clause, the original (not negated) formula is a tautology.